# Scout SDK: Multi language support for Advisor

Tags: android, skmaps

Using latest Scout SDK 2.5 with Android OS. Working on languages capabilities I see that with default SKMaps.zip we have voice commands for advisor only in EN.

Do we have option to download voice commands for other supported languages OTA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For prerecorded audio:** in the Android zip we only included the english files - in the iOS zip we've included the whole language set.

Either grab the languages from the iOS demo or download them from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0d4qx8xpeka6gh4/AADtdtsEFAezvvKdG3M7hKjja?dl=0) (replace those in the SKMaps.zip/Advisor/Languages folder)

**For text-to-speech:** you already have the config files in the default SKMaps.zip so no additinal work is needed - just switch the advisor language and make sure that the TTS options is used and it should work (see the [documentation](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec017) chapter for details)

Comment: Scout SDK have great support here in stack overflow. Thank you Ando.